# Filter listview in winform in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm having troubles solving a listview problema.
I have a listview that reads from a datatable that is connected to na sql database.
I want to be able to filter it throw a textbox textchanged handle, but i have the following issues?
 - Can´t backspace, the search won't update;
 - can't get the checked items;

```
 private void filtro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //searchData(filtro.Text);
        List<ListViewItem> showitems = new List<ListViewItem>();
        if (filtro.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = ListViewVistas.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var item = ListViewVistas.Items[i];

                if (item.Text.ToLower().Contains(filtro.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    item.BackColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                    item.ForeColor = SystemColors.InfoText;

                }
                else
                {
                    ListViewVistas.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            if (ListViewVistas.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                ListViewVistas.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
            UpdateViews();


public void UpdateViews()
    {
        ListViewVistas.Clear();

        //IR BUSCAR O DICIONARIO PARA DEPOIS VER SE AS VISTAS JA ESTAO ASSOCIADAS OU NÃO
        string m_IdFicheiroDesenho = "";
        NomeFicheiro FicheiroActivo = new NomeFicheiro();

        DataBase DbId = new DataBase();


        DbId.IdFichDesFromReferencia(FicheiroActivo.NomeReferencia, out m_IdFicheiroDesenho);

        Dictionary<int, List<string>> dicVistasFicheiroDesenho = DbId.GetDictionaryVistasFicheirosDesenho(m_IdFicheiroDesenho);

        string[] ListItemTxt = new string[4];

        ListViewVistas.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        ListViewVistas.GridLines = true;
        ListViewVistas.FullRowSelect = true;
        ListViewVistas.Columns.Add("Vista ou Sheet");
        ListViewVistas.Columns.Add("Ficheiro de Desenho");
        ListViewVistas.Columns.Add("Designação");
        ListViewVistas.Columns.Add("Id");
        ListViewVistas.Columns[0].Width = 230;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[1].Width = 180;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[1].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[2].Width = 420;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[2].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[3].Width = 30;
        ListViewVistas.Columns[3].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ListViewVistas.CheckBoxes = true;
        ListViewVistas.Items.Clear();

        if (checkBoxViews.Checked)...
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) sounds like it would be helpful, since it does everything you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code for loading data from the database so I can't comment directly on what you need to do but conceptually you should convert the loaded data into ListViewItems and store them in a List. This will be a master list that you will use for filtering.

```
List<ListViewItem> masterlist = new List<ListViewItem>();
```

This list should be available as a class level variable on your form.

In your TextChanged event you will then use the masterlist to retrieve the items that match your filter:

```
public void filtro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewVistas.Items.Clear();
    foreach(ListViewItem item in masterlist.Where(lvi => lvi.Text.ToLower().Contains(filtro.Text.ToLower())))
    {
        ListViewVistas.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

or if you're a fan of minimalism you can simplify the above to:

```
public void filtro_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewVistas.Items.Clear();
    ListViewVistas.Items.AddRange(masterlist.Where(lvi => lvi.Text.ToLower().Contains(filtro.Text.ToLower())).ToArray());
}
```

If you check a listviewitem it will remain checked as you are not re-creating the list view items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Handbag Crab for the answer, but that doesn't work.
This is part of the code that loads contente from the database

```
else
                if (!checkBoxAssociados.Checked)
                {
                    ListItemTxt[0] = view.ViewType.ToString() + ": " + view.ViewName.ToString();


                    ListItemTxt[1] = " -  ";
                    ListItemTxt[2] = "Vista não Associada!      Clique aqui para Associar Vista"; //POR DEFEITO A VISTA NÃO ESTÁ ASSOCIADA


                    //VER SE A VISTA ESTÁ ASSOCIADA OU NAO
                    if (dicVistasFicheiroDesenho.ContainsKey(view.Id.IntegerValue))
                    {
                        ListItemTxt[2] = dicVistasFicheiroDesenho[view.Id.IntegerValue][0];//Designacao
                        ListItemTxt[1] = dicVistasFicheiroDesenho[view.Id.IntegerValue][1];//Referencia
                    }


                    ListItemTxt[3] = view.Id.IntegerValue.ToString();
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(ListItemTxt);
                    ListViewVistas.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }

        if (checkBoxSheets.Checked)
        {
            foreach (Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewSheet viewSheet in m_selectViewsData.PrintableSheets)
            {
                ListItemTxt[0] = viewSheet.ViewType.ToString() + ": " + viewSheet.SheetNumber + " - " +
                    viewSheet.ViewName.ToString();


                ListItemTxt[1] = " -  ";
                ListItemTxt[2] = "Vista não Associada!      Clique aqui para Associar Vista"; //POR DEFEITO A VISTA NÃO ESTÁ ASSOCIADA

                //VER SE A VISTA ESTÁ ASSOCIADA OU NAO
                if (dicVistasFicheiroDesenho.ContainsKey(viewSheet.Id.IntegerValue))
                {
                    ListItemTxt[2] = dicVistasFicheiroDesenho[viewSheet.Id.IntegerValue][0];//Designacao
                    ListItemTxt[1] = dicVistasFicheiroDesenho[viewSheet.Id.IntegerValue][1];//Referencia 
                }

                ListItemTxt[3] = viewSheet.Id.IntegerValue.ToString();
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(ListItemTxt);
                ListViewVistas.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }

        if (ListViewVistas.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
        }
```